Tkinter displaying PY_VAR when attempting to set() value within Class() to display on Label
Sorry here is a rough pseudo code in place of the actual script as that is quite long
In essence, I declared a local 'value' StringVar() object which will be updated in the game engine class 'QuizGame' and the updated value should be displayed in the Label. However, it is either showing PY_VAR() or not updating at all.
It is similar to this Python Tkinter StringVar only displaying Py_Var(number) but I am trying to update a StringVar() object based on game condition/calculation rather than user's input.
from tkinter import *

# Game Engine
class QuizGame:
    .. init() and other methods...

    self.score gets updated => int() type
    value.set(str(self.score))

value = StringVar()
root = Tk()
Label(root, textvariable=value)
root.mainloop()


If a Label is displaying "PY_VAR0", then you most likely set its text= option to the StringVar, rather than textvariable=.

It is not clear what self.score is.  If you get "PY_VAR0", then self.score seems to be an instance of tkinter Variable.

Edit: Using Python 3.14, Windows 10.

However, it is either showing PY_VAR() or not updating at all.

The problem can be fixed.
You cannot place the root window immediately following StringVar.
You are missing geometry layout for Label widget.
Snippet:
from tkinter import *


# Game Engine
class QuizGame:
   def __init__(self):  

    self.score = 0
    value.set(str('self.score'))

root = Tk()
value = StringVar()
 
Label(root, textvariable=value).pack() 

QuizGame()
root.mainloop()

Screenshot:


The reason I received downvotes is that I am utilizing both Python 3.12 and 3.14. I do not encounter an error like PY_VAR(). I received an error that was too early to be called. That’s why I utilized the newest Python version to prevent errors.
